# Play Framework App on OpenShift

Tags: playframework, openshift

I have an OpenShift account and I'm trying out the free trial. I have a Scala web app built using Play framework. I now want to deploy this app to the Cartridge that I created with my free OpenShift trial. If I ssh into the OpenShift account, I get the following at my home:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4   62 Apr 24 02:21 app-deployments
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root                     4096 Apr 24 02:17 app-root
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root                     root                       85 Apr 24 02:22 gear-registry
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root                     root                       23 Apr 24 02:18 git
drwxr-xr-x. 10 4096 Apr 24 02:19 haproxy
drwxr-xr-x.  8   95 Apr 24 02:17 play2
```

I cloned the remote git repository that came with the Cartridge and it contained the dummy play framework structure. I can sure merge my stuff into this structure. But how do I build and start the server.

Even better would be to just use no cartridge as starting a Play framework does not need one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it:

```
1. Play dist - this would create the zip file in target/universal/

2. Copy the zip file to my git repo and push this file to the server using git push

3. Change the PLAY2_APPLICATION_PATH variable in ~/.profile in the server and point it to the zip file that I uploaded to the server
```

For more reference, here is the link:

https://github.com/tyrcho/openshift-cartridge-play2